# Java Locks/Condition Variable - signal() not waking up the thread

Tags: java, multithreading, signals, condition-variable, reentrantlock

so been stuck here, tried to look for answers, couldn't find any.
Simply, I keep trying to get the Train to signal to the Passenger that its in the station. Signal keeps looping but passenger just never wakes up.

I printed out the hashcode before signal/await and they're the same so the condition they're using should be the same.

Locks/Conditions are required so I can't use other sync techniques...

Train:

```
currStation.getLock().lock();

try{

System.out.println(currStation.getTrainCond().hashCode());
while(seats > 0 && currStation.getWaitingPassengers() > 0){
    currStation.getTrainCond().signal();
    //thread doesn't end.
    try {
            thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

try {
    thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

}
finally{
    currStation.getLock().unlock();
}
```

Passenger:

```
        station.getLock().lock();
    try {

        System.out.println(station.getTrainCond().hashCode());
        station.getTrainCond().await();

        while(!station.getSeat(this)){
            //keep running
            try {
                thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
            station.getLock().unlock();
        }
    }
```

station & currStation are the same object; thank you :) !

Comment: can you please explain the whole picture that you are going to program ?

Comment: There are multiple Stations and Passengers wait for a Train at a certain station. If a train enters a station, it signals passengers to board until all seats are full or all waiting passengers have boarded. Once seats full/passengers boarded, train leaves.all the functions like getting seats or setting the station the passenger/train is at works